# How to create Private Routes using React Router v6 Outlet AND localStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been away from coding, last time I've used React Router it was v5 yet. So, I'm working on a project and learned basics of V6 through some videos, learned about Outlet and wanted to use it. Now, I'm in another sprint of the project developing the login/logoff feats so now I need to protect some of those pages cause only logged users should access them 4 (Account/History/Deposit/Withdrawal). I've watched some videos but nothing could help me, is there somebody to give me the light? Code below.

```
index.js

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "account",
        element: <Account />,
      },
      {
        path: "history",
        element: <History />,
      },
      {
        path: "deposit",
        element: <Deposit />,
      },
      {
        path: "withdrawal",
        element: <Withdrawal />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

```
App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```